# Aligning two DIVs by their child element

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to figure out a way with CSS to layout semantically-defined multi-image figures, each image possibly with their own subcaptions. The semantic for this kind of figure is an outer `<figure>` div containing multiple `<figure class=subfigure>` divs. Each of the `.subfigure` divs contains exactly one `<img>` followed by a `<figcaption class=subfigcaption>`.

Here is a [minimal working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzUaC/8/)

**Goal:** *I'm trying to achieve a kind of layout that is common in print media*; each `.subfigure` is vertically aligned by the *baseline* of its unique `<img>` element, while its own `.subfigcaption` can run as long as it needs without affecting the relative positions of the `<img>` amongst each subfigure.

However, with my current layout code, I can only relatively align each `.subfigure` as a whole: the `<img>` and `.subfigcaption` is treated as an aggregate block. The result is, as can be seen [in my working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LzUaC/8/), that a long subcaption can ruin the image alignments between the subfigures.

I'd really like to find a CSS solution that does not require me to change the semantically-relavant HTML. I've considered using the table layout format, but I don't see how to place the table rows correctly given the way my html is currently organized. Also, this style would be applied to a large number of content, so I can't exactly tweak each specific figure by hand.

---

*Note:* doing `figure>figure {vertical-align: top;}` looks okay for this example but isn't what I'm looking for. The goal is to mimic a print convention, that we align at the *bottom* of the images, not the top. In fact, the more exact goal is to have all the `.subfigcaptions` start at a common baseline, regardless of the relative size of the images.

---

**Current layout**

[image]

**Desired layout**

[image]

Comment: Something like this? -http://jsfiddle.net/LzUaC/3/

Comment: Please see the newly added note. Thanks though!

Comment: I just added a temp class to the left image and gave the margin-top a minus value to create this - http://jsfiddle.net/LzUaC/4/

Comment: @SamJoy using fixed margin-top is not what the OP wants I think, also your demo is not good (try resizing the height of the window to see why).

Comment: To line-up the bottom-lines of the 2 images (may have different heights), they should be contained in the same container, this container **should not** contain the captions. That means you may have to change the layout (in HTML code) but I understand that doing so will make the layout less semantical (the `figcaption` should always goes right after the corresponding image).

Comment: @KingKing I agree it was only a temp fix, but the images need a container or wrapper

Comment: @KingKing yes, the problem is exactly how to achieve the layout I want without sacrificing the semantics, which is the whole point of my project int he first place.

Comment: more like this maybe ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dspwC/ ?

Comment: @GCyrillus hmmm, looks like there's no-longer an easy way to control the relative width of the img element then. thanks a lot for he effort though. I'll look more into it.

Comment: maybe a screen of what you expect ?

Comment: Will do so ASAP. Thank for the suggestion.

Comment: Examples added. Note that the images are always aligned at their baseline, regardless of image size or caption length, despite them being inside separate "figure" elements.

Comment: +1 for the baby seals :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the demo:

**http://jsfiddle.net/salman/LzUaC/29/**

And the idea:

- Use `display: inline-block` for sub figures so that:

  - They stack sideways
  - Their baselines align
- Place images with `width: 100%; height: auto;` inside sub figures

  - Optionally set `vertical-align: bottom;` to remove those few pixels at the bottom
- Place captions with `float: left;` inside sub figures so that:

  - They move out of the flow and do not affect the height of sub figure
  - Set `width: 100%;` to make them stretch all the way across sub figure
- Use `clear: both` on the last figure caption (I think you should however it does not seem to have any effect)

The CSS:

```
figure {
    margin: 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
figure > figure {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #AAA;
}
figure > figure > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
figure > figure > figcaption {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #999;
}
figure > figure + figcaption {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #666;
}
/*
 * for testing
 */
figure > figure:nth-child(1) {
    width: 31%;
}
figure > figure:nth-child(2) {
    width: 31%;
}
figure > figure:nth-child(3) {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Salman for pointing out that the real reason both this and the flex box thing worked is that they remove the sub caption from the flow of the images. I've made this the official answer.

Answer (score 11):

Err, am I missing something, or does just removing the `vertical-align: middle` give you the desired results:

http://jsfiddle.net/LzUaC/9/

[image]

Comment: Wow! I have no idea why, but this seems to work on all browsers except for IE<10! I don't know why it didn't occur to me in the first place to try this. Also, I'm perhaps more confused now than ever before. Why would this work? Does anyone know?

Comment: Seems that vertical-align: baseline is getting this effect. However, I really would like someone to explain how (or why) this works in more detail.!!

Comment: Further investigation indicates that if I remove the `flexbox` property of the caption elements, then the `vertical-align: baseline` no longer works. It's an interesting interaction between flexbox and non-flexbox elements. I don't know exactly how it works still, but I'll do some more experiments.

Comment: (This would also explain why it doesn't work for IE<10, since it doesn't support flexbox)

Comment: You can see example/info on baselines here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-css-flexbox-1-20140325/

Comment: I understand how baseline works *within* a flexbox, but realize that for this example, we have a mix of flexbox and *non*-flexbox elements within the same figure-div, and somehow all the flex-box elements are aligning with each-other *across* the `figure` element hierarchy boundary.

Comment: I've awarded this the bounty for being the first to discover a working solution. However, I feel that Salman A's solution below probably makes for a better "official" solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know this might scare you at first but give it a chance :-P You can always replace the tables with divs contenting display:table and table-cell.

This is about the only way I could think of to achieve this effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/LzUaC/5/

CSS

```
.fig-img{width:40%; text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom;}
.fig-img img{width:100%;}

.fig-caption{vertical-align:top;}

.fig-summary{text-align:center; padding-top:40px;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using the hard-coded HTML table layout (using `<table>`) is not recommended nowadays. Although using it can help us render any kind of layout. I'm a little sorry for the CSS table layout which sometimes can't replace HTML table layout because it does not support `colspan` and `rowspan`.

Comment: A table is definitely something that's on the table. However, I don't see an obvious way to make it work using `display:table` given how the HTML is organized. The table hierarchy is `tr>td`, which is exactly opposite to the `subfigure>(img+subcaption)` hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
figure>figure {
  vertical-align : middle;
}
figure>figcaption {
    display : -webkit-box;
    display : -moz-box;
    display : -ms-flexbox;
    display : -webkit-flex;
    display : flex;
}
```

and Adding

```
figure>figure>figcaption {
    vertical-align : top;   
           display : inline-block; 
}
figure>figcaption {
    text-align : center;
}
```

does the magic: <kbd>[running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/238A8/1/)</kbd>

Not using flex, and works everywhere... *except that in IE* (what a surprise...)

Comment: Actually, the flex boxes are kinda needed. I want the `figcaption`s to be fully-justified when there's two or more lines, and be centered when it only partially takes up one line. I don't know any other way to accomplish that without flexboxes (other than table hacks).

Comment: I though you was trying to avoid flex, after reading your comment from April 15, 20.19. Go with flex, then ;)